How to change the ripple color when an item is pressed in a navigation drawer
So I'm learning about how to incorporate the navigation drawer in my android app. I've successfully managed to incorporate it in my app. However, I cant find out how to change the ripple color when I press an item. I've used the following attribute
app:itemRippleColor="@color/purple"

to try and change the default grey ripple color. However it is not working

Can someone guide me? Also I would appreciate it if someone can tell me how to add custom animation when I press the item

@BobSmith I tried using app:itemRippleColor="@color/your_ripple_color" within the item tags in the menu file. But it didnt work. Unfortunately I cant add snaps here in the comments otherwise I could them to you

Answer 1:
In your navigation drawer menu layout file in menu item add the attribute itemRippleColor like below :
main_menu.xml
<item
    android:id="@+id/your_menu_item_id"
    android:title="Your Menu Item Title"
    app:itemRippleColor="@color/your_ripple_color" />

Answer 2:
menu_item_animation.xml
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_pressed="true">
      <objectAnimator
          android:propertyName="scaleX"
          android:duration="200"
          android:fromValue="1.0"
          android:toValue="1.1" />
      <objectAnimator
          android:propertyName="scaleY"
          android:duration="200"
          android:fromValue="1.0"
          android:toValue="1.1" />
  </item>
  <item>  </item>
</selector>

Navigation drawer menu layout xml :
<item
    android:id="@+id/your_menu_item_id"
    android:title="Your Menu Item Title"
    android:onClick="onMenuItemClick"  />

As you are using java currently :
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void onMenuItemClick(View view) {
        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.menu_item_press);
        view.startAnimation(animation);
        // Handle menu item selection logic here
    }
}


I tried using app:itemRippleColor="@color/your_ripple_color"  within the item tags in the menu file. However, it didnt work

@humble for this to work you have to add on item click and inside that add animation then only you can see the effect

I didnt try adding animation as there seems to be a builtin animation. However, I did try answer 1. Unfortunately that didnt work . However, I have found a solution using the style attribute within the Navigation View
